# Multiple selections on a listview with arrayadapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am running into a problem that I am having a little trouble solving. I have implemented a custom listivew that uses an arrayadapter to let me have rows that have 5 images and two text fields in them. They look like the image below...
http://postimg.org/image/tj5ku3wux/

What I would like to do is to be able to select multiple lines at the same time (and keep them highlighted until I perform some sort of action with either the options menu or a button. However, I cannot seem to select multiple items, even though I have enabled `android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"`. Also, I cannot have checkboxes in my layout, so I would like to be able to highlight the rows without it. I have included my source below.

I guess I am trying to figure out how to select multiple items WITHOUT using checkboxes. Thanks

**row_format.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!--  ListRow Left side Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/h_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/h_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/h_address"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/h_name"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"  />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/h_recording"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/h_low_battery"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/h_low_disk"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="85dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/h_streaming"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="125dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/Hlist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly: you can color the items and store picked positions

```
    List<Integer> selected;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    selected = new ArrayList<Long>();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); //mark clicked row
            selected.add(id); //store position of clicked row and to something with it at the end
        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: If you have any questions just ask

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I needed. Simple yet perfect. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

You can try contextual action bar. Sample application is here  http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-delete-multiple-selected-items-listview-tutorial/